# Explode dentro de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentado generar un script dentro del Controller para buscar una cadena de texto dentro de un campo de la base de datos.

Lo estoy realizando con la función explode, pero no me hace la variable obtenida de la base de datos dentro del explode.

```
$separacion = explode('<div id="$link_href" class="modal">', $productos_promo['promociones']);
```

Como puedo hacer para que la variable $link_href que viene de la base de datos me lo obtenga correctamente??

Comment: Realmente no entiendo nada, explícame eso de **buscar una cadena de texto con la función explode**, y otra cosa que no entiendo ¿Qué debe obtener correctamente `$link_href`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para desplegar una cadena de texto, tienes que revisar el uso de **comillas simples o dobles**, las comillas simples son para cadenas literales, no reemplazan referencias a variables.

Cuando usas comillas dobles, son para cadenas escapadas, por lo que si utilizas una variable, si se va a referenciar, en tu caso, tienes comillas simples que cubren toda tu cadena, por eso no ves la variable.

```
'<div id="$link_href" class="modal">'
```

Solamente debes de cambiar las comillas o concatenar los valores, como se te haga más sencillo.

```
"<div id='$link_href' class='modal'>"
'<div id="' . $link_href . '" class="modal">'
```

De esa forma, vas a poder ver tu variable.